# C# All forms but Owner sent to back when I hide a ShowDialog form

Tags: c#, forms, winforms, hide, showdialog

A form is shown using ShowDialog(this). User closes it and instead of disposing it I want to preserve changes and keep it ready till next open call:

```
        private FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
```

But hiding the dialog results in sending to back all other opened forms but the Owner. Using Show(this) instead of ShowDialog() fixes it but I need to keep it opening as a dialog.

Comment: You don't need to hide it. Keep a reference to the form and show it again when you need.

Comment: Btw, you don't need that code. `ShowDialog` does not close/dispose the form - see [Form.ShowDialog](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: You can read the **Remarks** section of [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2) which is also mentioned by @IvanStoev.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to hide it. Keep a reference to the form and show it again when you need:

```
YourDialogForm f;
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(f==null)
        f = new YourDialogForm();

    f.ShowDialog();
}
```

More information:

- [`ShowDialog`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2)
- [`DialogResult`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx)

---

Also if it is a setting form, you can add/use the `Settings.settings` file in your project and load and save settings. This way you don't need to rely on the form state. This way you can [`bind controls properties to settings properties`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wabtadw6(v=vs.100).aspx) and then call `Properties.Settings.Default.Save();` when closing form.

Comment: Thanks, that solves the problem. Are You sure garbage collector won't dispose it sometime in the future while being low on memory?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a class to hold your state

```
public class yourFormState{
 //Assign your properties here        
}


private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
     CreateConfigData();
}

private void CreateConfigData() {
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("yourConfig.xml")) {
    state.ButtonBackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.ToHtml(button1.BackColor);
    XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFormState));
    ser.Serialize(sw, state);
}
```

}

and on your form load you can load your config and access the data

```
  private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    if (File.Exists("Yourconfig.xml")) {
    loadConfig();
} //Assign your properties


private void loadConfig() {
XmlSerializer ser = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyFormState));
using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("Yourconfig.xml")) {
    state = (MyFormState)ser.Deserialize(fs);
}
```